# Outlook web add in with Graph API - Inline images not displaying when sending current item as an Outlook Item attachment

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am able to send my current item as an attachment , but i am running into a problem where if there are any inline images within my current item, These do not display properly when i open my current item as an attachment from my newly sent/received mail. I understand that the image src is incorrect after sending my original email as an attachment, but im not sure how to rectify this or if this is expected behaviour because i have missed something.

My aim is to forward my current item/email as it appears, as an outlook item to the recipients mailbox.

Im wondering is there an error in how i have set up my json which i post to the Graph API to send mail ? i will post it below incase anything stands out as being set up wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
  var email = client.api('/me/messages/' + restID).get();

    var attachments = client.api('/me/messages/' + restID + '/attachments').get()

    const sendMail = {
        message: {
            subject:  'This contains my original email',// forwardMailSubject,
            body: {
                contentType: "Text",
                content: 'Test' // forwardMailBody
            },
            toRecipients: [
                {
                    emailAddress: {
                        address: 'test12321@outlook.com' //forwardMailbox
                    }
                }
            ],
            attachments: [
                {
                    '@odata.type': "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
                    'name': "attachment",
                    'contentType': "html",
                    'item': {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
                        "id": email.id,
                        "createdDateTime": email.createdDateTime,
                        "lastModifiedDateTime": email.lastModifiedDateTime,
                        "receivedDateTime": email.receivedDateTime,
                        "sentDateTime": email.sentDateTime,
                        "hasAttachments": true,
                        "internetMessageId": email.internetMessageId,
                        "subject": "Reminder - please bring laptop",
                        "importance": "normal",
                        "conversationId": email.conversationId,
                        "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
                        "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
                        "isRead": false,
                        "isDraft": false,
                        "webLink": email.webLink,
                        "body": email.body,
                        "sender": email.sender,
                        "from": email.from,
                        "toRecipients": email.toRecipients,
                        "attachments": attachments
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    client.api('/me/sendMail')
        .post(sendMail);
```

Comment: You're correct. In Graph API call, you have has attachments property which indicates whether the message has attachments. This property doesn't include inline attachments, so if a message contains only inline attachments, this property is false. In order to verify the existence of inline attachments, you need to parse the body property to look for a src attribute, such as <IMG src="cid:image001.jpg@01D26CD8.6C05F070">. Try this approach and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried setting hasAttachments to false after verifying my email only has inline attachments, but still the same outcome. The email bodys img src's match the contentIDs that i have in my attachments object array also

Comment: hmm, ok. The above worked for me though. 

What type of message is this - HTML or RTF? Not sure they differ though.

Comment: The email im currently testing is HTML yea. In terms of how my code is set up, is it much different to the way you had got it to successfully work for yourself ?

Comment: Still unable to work this one out. For clarity, attaching the current item to an email and sending it works(currrent email attaches OK to email as outlook item). What doesnt work / what isnt working as expected, is any attachments that are supposed to be included in the email that ive just sent as an attachment. I.e inline images/ any other attachments to the email that im attaching as an 'itemAttachment'. Its essentially attachments within my attachment that arent sending, if that makes sense